# Does c# have a rspec like testing framework that makes grouping like tests together?

Tags: c#, nunit

I want a testing framework that makes it easier to group like tests together.

I like how rpsec makes it easier to group similiar tests together, can you do this with any .net based framework?

I'm using nunit at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked out [NSpec](http://nspec.org/)?

Comment: MSpec - https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications has a nicer more fluent syntax than NSpec IMHO

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you looking for NUnit Category attribute?
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2